# VBA for aggregating values and drilldown

Tags: excel, vba, drilldown

Can someone point me to the right direction. Customer list with where column A contains names. The same name can appear more than once on column A. On column B i have the amount they have ordered. The same name may have ordered several times. Therefore the situation could be

```
Column A  |Column B 
Customer1|1
Customer2|20
Customer1|21
Customer3|15
Customer4|1
Customer4|6
```

Basically I need to Pivot these with VBA by customer to another sheet, without using Pivot. So i need something that finds the unique values and the summarises the orders. Also i need to be able to drilldown (separate feature i guess) to the invoices. Can someone help me with the first task of "Pivoting"? The outcome should be something like:

```
Drilldown|Customer1|22
Drilldown|Customer2|20
Drilldown|Customer3|15
Drilldown|Customer4|7
```

Comment: Please include the code you are using that you need help with in your question.

Comment: Hint: You can use `Dictionary` object to summarize results in VBA.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the tip, ill look in to this. Although it doesnt seem too easy :)

Comment: Hi, i got the concept of the Dictionary, but if i want to send my file, everyone would need to "tick" the Microsoft Scripting Runtime. Is there a work-around for this feature, i believe this would solve the problem.

Comment: Use late-binding

Comment: `Dim Dict As Object: Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")` then you don't need to click anything @Carlsberg789. Thought once you click it, it stays clicked because it's a file thing so everyone would have it enabled.